# How To Resize Images On Upload

Tags: php

Is there a **PHP** function or someway that you know of that images can be resized proportionally on let say, a upload?

Comment: You can use the GD library (http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or the ImageMagicK Library (http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php). I think GD is included in the default PHP install, but you may have to add ImageMagick yourself.

Comment: Also take a look to [timthumb](http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a class of functions called Imagic which uses the ImageMagic tools (If I remember correctly).

You need Imagick::resizeImage, the documentation for which is found [Here.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php)